Is there a function that I could use in my “Select” or “Where” that would keep rows that cancel each other out from pulling into the extract?
I have a script that pulls back charges for services.  Sometimes a service is charged, then cancelled as shown in screenshot below.  I was wondering if there is a function that I could use in my “Select” or “Where” that would keep those rows that cancel each other out from pulling into the extract?:
Code:
SELECT
 c.service_dt_tm "Service Date",
 c.item_price,
 c.charge_type_cd

FROM
 charge c,

 customer e

WHERE
 c.bill_item_id = 363803 AND
 c.charge_description = 'Oil Change' AND
 c.customer_id = e.customer_id AND

 e.active_ind = 1 AND
 e.customer_type_cd IN (9489, 9480, 9488) AND
 e.garage_loc_cd = 8473

Things I have tried but have not had any luck:
“Case” in the “Where” clause
“Match_Recognize”
Any and all help, directions, suggestions, guidance, references greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Roland

check exists clause.

You haven't defined what you mean by "cancelling each other out". However that logic works, it will likely involve comparing multiple rows, which can be done with analytic functions and with subqueries. But without data or examples of rows that cancel each other, we wouldn't know how to suggest any more specific.

Sorry @Paul W  Screenshot got stripped.  Posting now.

Please do not post images of data. [Edit] your post and include the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data as text we can copy/paste and execute and the expected output as markdown formatted text.

@MT0 Will adjust post.  Thank you.

Count the number of rows of each type and filter out the rows where both types exist:
SELECT service_dt_tm AS "Service Date",
       item_price,
       charge_type_cd
FROM   (
  SELECT c.service_dt_tm,
         c.item_price,
         c.charge_type_cd,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY c.customer_id,
                        c.service_dt_tm,
                        ABS(c.item_price),
                        c.charge_type_cd
           ORDER BY     NULL
         ) AS rn,
         LEAST(
           COUNT(CASE c.charge_type_cd WHEN 1577 THEN 1 END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY c.customer_id, c.service_dt_tm, ABS(c.item_price)
             ORDER BY NULL
           ),
           COUNT(CASE c.charge_type_cd WHEN 1576 THEN 1 END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY c.customer_id, c.service_dt_tm, ABS(c.item_price)
             ORDER BY NULL
           )
         ) AS num_matched
  FROM   charge c
         INNER JOIN customer e
         ON c.customer_id = e.customer_id
  WHERE  c.bill_item_id = 363803
  AND    c.charge_description = 'Oil Change'
  AND    e.active_ind = 1
  AND    e.customer_type_cd IN (9489, 9480, 9488)
  AND    e.garage_loc_cd = 8473
)
WHERE  rn > num_matched;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE charge (customer_id, service_dt_tm, item_price, charge_type_cd, bill_item_id, charge_description) AS
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1970-01-01 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.15, 1577, 363803, 'Oil Change' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1970-01-01 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), -2.15, 1576, 363803, 'Oil Change' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1970-01-01 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.15, 1577, 363803, 'Oil Change' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1970-01-01 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.15, 1577, 363803, 'Oil Change' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE customer (customer_id, active_ind, customer_type_cd, garage_loc_cd) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 9489, 8473 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



Service Date
ITEM_PRICE
CHARGE_TYPE_CD




1970-01-01 12:34:56
2.15
1577


1970-01-01 12:34:56
2.15
1577



fiddle

That worked perfectly @fiddle  Thank you!!
